# difficult understanding memory address in Intel's vtune tool

Tags: windbg, dump, intel-vtune

[image]

In the above image, I have used vtune tool to see process's flow.

Also dumped memory for windbg.

I intend to see if that Engine.dll+840c1 disassembled section in windbg, but

seems result is different.

Can you guys tell what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: It's not clear to me how you got from 0x100840bd to Engine+0x840c1

Answer (score 0):

[Engine.dll] in stack of VTune does not actually mean the load address of Engine.dll library (as you treat it in WinDbg). It represents some unresolved function from this library. When there is no debug info for the module, VTune uses [Module name] representation as a **function name** for all the functions inside this module. VTune is able to recognize function boundaries using static analysis - so all the functions from Engine.dll with performance data or appeared in stack which are not exported functions (like DllUnregisterServer) will be represented as [Engine.dll].

Try to disasm Engine.dll via e.g. dumpbin tool - the addresses should match those that you see in VTune so you'd be able to compare or verify disasm view in VTune.

Comment: thanks for the apply.
I did a few test on it.
I found that vtune's module entry point and dump file's module entry point was different.
Also tried match disassembled code, but it isn't exactly the same. It was but comparable.
When I match the module entry point, I've found that function's addresses are pointing correct location.

Lastly, I've got a question. Do you mean that vtune have dumpbin tool inside it?

Comment: [dumpbin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx) is a part of MS Visual Studio. You can also change assembly syntax in [VTune options](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/544340).